# Passing variables into WP shortcode - Events Manager plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

php beginner here - forgive my naivete....

Just found this wonderful community.

I'm creating a site using the WP plugin [Events Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/events-manager/).

The plugin provides some "out of the box" shortcodes which can generate lists of events via variables and placeholders. For example:

```
[events_list tag="Theatre"&state="Brussels"&scope="tomorrow"]
#_EVENTLINK - at #_LOCATIONLINK on #_EVENTDATES at #_EVENTTIMES
[/events_list]
```

What I would like to do is to populate the variables in this shortcode (scope, state, tag, etc) with optional user-selected terms via a multiple dropdown menu, submitted from a previous page. The approach I am taking is to generate a URL when the menu selection is submitted, which takes the user to the page with the shortcode, for example:

```
mysite.com/?page_id=1001&tag=Theatre&state=Brussels&scope=tomorrow
```

My question is, can anyone suggest how I might get the variables down from the URL to the shortcode, so that they automatically drive the shortcode to generate the required events list as per users' changing selections? I have tried using a php snippet (via an insertion plugin) such as

```
<?php
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["scope"]);
?>
```

but seem to be running into problems re nested shortcodes, or other conflicts running php in Wordpress page.

Would greatly appreciate any tips as to what direction I might take!!!

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Get the query string with: `$awQueryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`

Parse the query string with: `parse_str($awQueryString, $awQueryStringParams);`

And then echo out your shortcode like this: `echo do_shortcode('[events_list tag="' . $awQueryStringParams['tag'] . '" state="' . $awQueryStringParams['state'] .  '" scope="' . $awQueryStringParams['scope'] . '"]');`

So the full snippet would be:

```
<?php
    $awQueryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    parse_str($awQueryString, $awQueryStringParams);
    echo do_shortcode('[events_list tag="' . $awQueryStringParams['tag'] . '" state="' . $awQueryStringParams['state'] .  '" scope="' . $awQueryStringParams['scope'] . '"]');
?>
```

I don't know why, but when testing this on my dev site I would get a 404 when I tried to use your actual query string parameter `tag`. This may be something local to my environment/site, but if you get a 404 using this solution it may have to do with the `tag` QSP.

**Edit in response to your comment regarding checking if the query string exists or not:**

```
<?php
    $awQueryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    parse_str($awQueryString, $awQueryStringParams);
    if (empty($awQueryString)) {
        echo 'No Results';
    } else {
        echo do_shortcode('[events_list tag="' . $awQueryStringParams['tag'] . '" state="' . $awQueryStringParams['state'] .  '" scope="' . $awQueryStringParams['scope'] . '"]');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Andy this is just perfect-  you are the MAN!! I did change the string parameter `tag` to `what` in line with my shortcode and it works like a dream. Many, many thanks....

Comment: Could you indulge me with one more tip: how do I stop the shortcode from being triggered if there is no query string in the URL? I ask because if I go to the page `mysite.com/?page_id=1001` without any query (which curious users might just do...) then it generates all of my events past present and future. I'm fiddling with something like `if (isset($the_var)) {
  echo "No results";
} else {
  //your original excellent code
}` but to no avail for the moment!

Comment: Sure, let me modify my answer real quick.

Comment: Check my answer now.